# datetime input format error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

When I input the data on the form I get an error saying "when converting a string to datetime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the `DateTime` object". I tried changing the string format and hardcoded the `viewModel.Date`, `viewModel.Time` but I still get an error when can anyone suggest an way of overcoming this?

```
public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
{
    var artistId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var artist = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == artistId);
    var genre = _context.Genres.Single(g => g.Id == viewModel.Genre);
    var gig = new Gig
    {
        Àrtist = artist,
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)),
        Genre = genre,
        Venue = viewModel.Venue
    };
    _context.Gigs.Add(gig);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}


public class Gig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Àrtist { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

}

public class GigFormViewModel
{
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int Genre { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `viewModel.Date` and `viewModel.Time`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)),
```

you should put "space" between `{0}` and `{1}`:

```
DateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}", viewModel.Date, viewModel.Time)),
```

Comment: thanks very much didn't realize the space would be a issue

Comment: Hi Roma, yes that solved my issue. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: @gkhan if this answer resolved your problem, then mark it as an solution, please.